# .NET core Pass Commandline Args to Startup.cs from Program.cs

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to configure kestrel so that when it's in it's raw mode it runs on a specific port. However to do so it appears that the launchsettings.json needs to pass command line args to do so since there is no straight up option and it always runs on port 5000 which will obviously conflict if you have an api you need to run and a website.

So I added the CommandLine package to my site and you can indeed use builder.AddCommandLine() in the startup.cs file.

The problem is how to get the args from the program.cs to the Startup.cs or look them up other than a static variable.

Kind of makes the extension method pointless if you can't get at the args.

Any better ways of doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so you can run your app with a port specified on the command line, like `dotnet run myproject --port 3333`?

Comment: Yes or let vs.Net or vs code specify a unique port so two sites can be run at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I actually found what seems more elegant solution:

1. Parse command line arguments into `IConfigurationRoot` in Program (using CommandLineApplication, good article & examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763239.aspx))
2. Just pass this `IConfigurationRoot` to `Startup` via DI container.

Like so:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    var configuration = LoadConfiguration(args);

    // Use Startup as always, register IConfigurationRoot to services
    return new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseConfiguration(configuration)
        .ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(configuration))
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        // You get configuration in Startup constructor or wherever you need
    }
}
```

Example implementation of LoadConfiguration, which parses args and builds `IConfigurationRoot` (in this example configuration file name can be overridden in command line arguments):

```
private static IConfigurationRoot LoadConfiguration(string[] args)
{
    var configurationFileName = "configuration.json";

    var cla = new CommandLineApplication(throwOnUnexpectedArg: true);

    var configFileOption = cla.Option("--config <configuration_filename>", "File name of configuration", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);

    cla.OnExecute(() =>
    {
        if (configFileOption.HasValue())
            configurationFileName = configFileOption.Value();

        return 0;
    });

    cla.Execute(args);

    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
        .AddJsonFile(configurationFileName, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You can instantiate Startup class by yourself and pass it as instances to WebHostBuilder. It is somewhat not so elegant, but doable. From [here.](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/333#issuecomment-211727037)

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    // Load configuration and append command line args
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
        .AddJsonFile("configuration.json")
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    // pass config to Startup instance
    var startup = new Startup(config);

    // Instead of using UseStartup<Startup>()
    // Register startup to services
    return new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseSetting("applicationName", "Your.Assembly.Name")
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<IStartup>(startup))
        .Build();
}
```

Couple of caveats are:

- by doing so, Startup should implement `IStartup` which is limited for `Configure` method in parameters to only `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` instead of full `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)`
- For some reason, you need to specify `applicationName` parameter manually as in my example. I'm testing this on `2.0.0-preview1-final`

Comment: Yuk, but ok. This stuff should be trivially implemented and easy to set in vs.net 2017. But no, it's a hack.

Answer (score 15):

A simple solution is to access the command line arguments through the [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.71).aspx/html) method.

You only need to make sure that you remove the first argument, which is the executable name:

```csharp
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).ToArray();
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.AddCommandLine(args);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perferctly and is a simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

Kestrel can be configured to listen on a different port in several ways.  None of these methods need to happen in the `Startup` class, but rather in the `Main` method of the `Program` class.  Using the `AddCommandLine` extension method is one of them.  To use that, modify your Program.cs file's `Main` method to look something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

Then, run the application with `dotnet run --server.urls http://*:<yourport>`, replacing `<yourport>` with the actual port number that you want it to run on.  The `*` makes it listen on all available IP addresses, if you want to listen on a specific address then you need to specify it there instead of the `*`.

Another option for changing the port is to use the `.UseUrls` method to hard-code the port and address.  For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls("http://*:8080")
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

This example will make your application listen on port `8080` on all available IP addresses.

Comment: My issue with that is now the startup is decoupled from startup.cs and injecting stuff for testing is no longer possible in the correct sense because the config creation is happening in main ND not startup.  Also putting in the use URLs seems fine but I'm hoping that won't mess with azure deploy?

Comment: If you use the AddCommandLine option it shouldn't interfere with azure deploy since it will only change the port if it's specified on the command-line.

Comment: OK, but that still decouples config creation with startup.cs and di.

Comment: @DanielGrim he needs to pass the command line arguments to Startup, your solution does not address that.