# .NET Core Web Project - Using Command Line Arguments

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to pass in the DbConnectionString via command line argument to my .NET Core Web API app.

After reading:

[.NET core Pass Commandline Args to Startup.cs from Program.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290566/net-core-pass-commandline-args-to-startup-cs-from-program-cs)

My Program.cs looks something like:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args) {

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();
        var host = new WebHostBuilder() 
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

So now... I have added the command line args to the collection of key value pair configs of my WebHostBuider...

However, In Startup.cs is where I register everything such as my DbContext (which requires the DbConnectionString passed as a command line arg)

My Startup constructor looks like this:

```
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Because previously, my connection string was being stored in a Config file.

My Question is - How do I access the Command Line args from within Startup.cs ??
I have tried constructor injection with IConfiguration and IConfigurationRoot in Startup.cs but neither of these are registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing

```
.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(config))
```

In my program.cs. Fixed version as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();
        var host = new WebHostBuilder() 
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(config))
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }`
```

Comment: And how do you pass the params exactly? I am looking for similar implementation and my need is to bind the configurations to a model class. The specific param/property can be either from appsettings.json (which works if i pass) or from command line (which i dont know the right syntax to pass that would get bound to my property)

Comment: Like this: 
```
// Configure the Configuration items
            services.Configure<AppConfigurations>(config => Configuration.Bind(config));
```