# How to add command line arguments to Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, .net-core

Locally we can do `dotnet run [args]` or `dotnet publish` followed by `dotnet mydll.dll [args]`.

When deploying that App to an Azure Web App under App Services, how do you make it startup with these command line arguments?

Comment: Something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290566/net-core-pass-commandline-args-to-startup-cs-from-program-cs

Comment: What are these args for? Just for configuration? If yes, I would do the configuration using environment variables or appsettings as well. With this option you are able to set the args in the azure portal in the application settings of that specific app service.

Comment: Juergen leave that as an answer, and I'll approve it. Using appsettings and the added bonus of being able to configure them from azure portal seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Kudu API Rest to execute command lines operations.

Documentation: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API

```
POST /api/command
```

Executes an arbitrary command line and return its output

```
{
"command": 'echo Hello World',
"dir": 'site\\repository'
}
```

The JSON body of the post should look like this, passing the command and the folder it should run in.

You need to use Basic Auth (Get your credentials in Overview / Get Publish Profile Section) in order to make a POST request.

Comment: Isn't there a better way?